# Font awesome icon showing circle with question mark

Tags: html, css

I bought template for website that included font awesome icons, but I needed fa fa-bone witch was not included so i searched web and found here https://fontawesome.com/icons/bone?style=solid .
I used it like every time before pasting link in `<head>` and putting it in `<i class="fas fa-bone"></i>` but it is showing circle with question mark.

Can it be because i already have another font awesome library ?
**head section**

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-rdyFrfAIC05c5ph7BKz3l5NG5yEottvO/DQ0dCrwD8gzeQDjYBHNr1ucUpQuljos"crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384u5J7JghGz0qUrmEsWzBQkfvc8nK3fUT7DCaQzNQ+q4oEXhGSx+P2OqjWsfIRB8QT" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <div class="funfact-item">
   <i class="fas fa-bone"></i>
  <h2><span class="counter">200+</span></h2>
  <p>Bones eaten</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `another font awesome library `? what libary? or previous version of FA? also show us your code

Comment: share your full code so we can see that question mark

Comment: @לבנימלכה Updated see please

Comment: as you can see it's working fine here, so check if you missed something

Comment: inspect element by using F12 and see there what happen to your head tag

Comment: No everything is same I am really confused

Comment: <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-bone fa-w-16" style="font-weight: 600;" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="bone" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">...

Comment: It might be that your using new icons and thats not the tag for it, try with 4.1 font awesome icons version